# Spring batch save arabic caracters in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, arabic, arabic-support

I want to save an arabic caracters in mysql, in my CSV file i've both arabic and english caracters.

When i show the console log i can see my string with arabic caracters, but in MySQL i see '????" caracters

Both if my CSV file, database and table are in UTF-8 encoding

I've also add this in application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contacts?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

I'm using Spring Batch version 4, with simple CSV to MySQL

what i must added ?

Additional code :

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Csv> fileReader(@Value("${input}") Resource in) throws Exception {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Csv>()
                .name("file-reader")
                .resource(in)
                .targetType(Csv.class)
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .delimited().delimiter(";").names(new String[]{"Name","Email","UID","Username","Phone","Location","Birthday","Gender"})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Contact> jdbcWriter(DataSource ds) {
            return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Contact>()
                    .dataSource(ds)
                    .sql("INSERT INTO contact (UID, name, username, gender, phone, email, birthday, location, country_id, city_id, state_id) VALUES (:uid, :name, :username, :gender, :phone, :email, :birthday, :location, :countryId, :cityId, :stateId)")
                    .beanMapped()
                    .build();

    }
```

Comment: Can you please check if the database already accepted arabic values ?

Comment: how to check this ?

Comment: you can simply just add a simple value manually from dbms
also please provide us some code how do you read this CSV

Comment: Yes, it accept, i've tried to insert manualy with arabic caracters, it save well ...

Comment: Okay please provide us how do you read this csv and how you are inserting it  to database

Comment: i update my post

Comment: The default encoding used by the `FlatFileItemReader` is the value of `Charset.defaultCharset()` of your JVM (which might not be `UTF-8`). Can you try to specify the encoding explicity on your reader with `new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Csv>()
                .name("file-reader")
                .resource(in).encoding("UTF-8")...` and see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: when i add it, i've : The method encoding(String) is undefined for the type FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Csv>

Comment: This method is available in 4.0.1 version. If you use the 4.0.0 version, you need to create the reader without the builder and use the setter `setEncoding` to set the encoding.

Comment: I change my version to 4.0.1.RELEASE, when i run the app i got this error : 

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '' into a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: no such class found

Comment: ok in this case, I would recommend fixing one issue at a time. Can you try to create the reader without the builder and set the encoding with the setter? Does this fix your encoding issue?